# Sum of Digits in a specific way in Python

Tags: python, sum, digits

I'm looking for a code that runs, i.e:

```
    int(input) = 2565
```

Printed Output should be like:

```
    2 + 5 + 6 + 5  = 18 = 1 + 8 = 9
```

I wrote the code that gives final answer "9". But I couldn't managed to write it with every digit separated "+" sign. Assuming that I need to use while loop but how can I write the code so it will be like the output above?

Comment: Not clear what you want. That output printed? With or without "Output = "? Or as a string? And why are there two spaces before one of the equal signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with the `end` keyword argument of the [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function which is the last character/string that print will put after all of its arguments are, well, printed, by default is `"\n"` but it can be change to your desire.

And the [.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method from string which put the given string between the given list/iterable of strings to get the desire result:

```
>>> " + ".join("123")
'1 + 2 + 3'
>>>
```

Mixing it all together:

```
def sum_digit(n):
    s = sum(map(int,str(n)))
    print(" + ".join(str(n)),"=",s, end="")
    if s<10:
        print()
        return s
    else:
        print(" = ",end="")
        return sum_digit(s)
```

Here we first get the sum of the digit on `s`, and print it as desire, with `end=""` print will not go to the next line which is necessary for the recursive step, then we check if done, and in that case print a new empty line if not we print an additional `=` to tie it for the next recursive step

```
>>> sum_digit(2565)
2 + 5 + 6 + 5 = 18 = 1 + 8 = 9
9
>>>
```

This can be easily be modify to just return the accumulated string by adding an extra argument or to be iterative but I leave those as exercise for the reader :)

Comment: This is the most clear solution so far and thank you so much.

Comment: my pleasure, if mine or any of the other answers given here solve your question consider accepting it so we know that the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
def sum_of_digits(s):
    if s < 10:
        return s
    return sum_of_digits(sum(int(c) for c in str(s)))
    
> sum_of_digits(2565)
9
```

It recursively checks if the numerical value is less than 10. If it does, it returns this value. If not, it adds the digits, then recursively calls itself on the result.

**Edit**

To print out the steps as it goes along, you could do something like this:

```
def sum_of_digits(s):
    if s < 10:
        print(s)
        return s
    print(' + '.join(c for c in str(s)) + ' = ')
    return sum_of_digits(sum(int(c) for c in str(s)))
```

Comment: Isn't that just what they have already, not what they're asking for?

Comment: @superbrain Not sure what you mean. The question was how to code it, and iterating over the characters of the string cast is the answer I'm suggesting.

Comment: They said they already have code to compute the final answer. And to me it looks like they want to show the path to the final answer as well. I asked a clarification question now.

Comment: @superbrain Perhaps the OP will clarify it in their answer to your question, then.

Comment: Apparently the OP can't be bothered to reply to me, but they did somewhat clarify [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944511/sum-of-digits-in-a-specific-way-in-python#comment114820284_64944576).

Comment: @superbrain Ah, got it. Good for you for reading carefully. I updated the answer to reflect my current understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry I've just seen the edit. This looks very understanable. Thank you for your concern. Gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

First, initiate an empty string `output_str`.
With a while loop which contniues when our integer is > 9:

1. `[s for s in str(x)]` would create a list of the digits (as strings) of our integer. It's called a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), is very useful, and my advice is to read a bit about it.
2. With `" + ".join()` we create a string with " + " between the
   digits. Add this string at the end of `output_str`.
3. Add `" = "` to the end of `output_str`.
4. Calculate the sum of the digits (we cannot use `sum(lst_of_digits)` because it's a list of strings. `sum([int(s) for s in lst_of_digits])` converts the string list into an inter list, which can be summed using `sum()`). Store the sum into `x`.
5. Add the new `x` + `" = "` to `output_string`.

At the end of the string, we have a redundant " = " (because the last (5) was not needed), let's just remove the last 3 chars (`=`) from it.

```
x = 2565
output_str = ""
while x > 9:
    lst_of_digits = [s for s in str(x)]
    output_str += " + ".join(lst_of_digits)
    output_str += " = "
    x = sum([int(s) for s in lst_of_digits])
    output_str += f"{x} = "
output_str = output_str[:-3]
```

outputs:
`output_str = '2 + 5 + 6 + 5 = 18 = 1 + 8 = 9'`

Comment: These step by step explanations are so useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob but this should do what you want.

Cheers,
Guglielmo

```
import math
import sys

def sumdigits(number):

    digits = []
    for i in range( int(math.log10(number)) + 1):
      digits.append(int(number%10))
      number = number/10

    digits.reverse()
    string = ''
    thesum = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(digits):
      string += str(x)
      thesum += x
      if i != len(digits)-1: string += ' + '
      else: string += ' = '

    if thesum > 10:
      return string,thesum,int(math.log10(number))+1
    else:
      return string,thesum,0


def main():

    number = float(sys.argv[1])
    finalstring = ''

    string,thesum,order = sumdigits(number)
    finalstring += string
    finalstring += str(thesum)
    
    while order > 0:
      finalstring += ' = '
      string,thesum,order = sumdigits(thesum)

      finalstring += string
      finalstring += str(thesum)


    print 'myinput = ',int(number)
    print 'Output = ',finalstring

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you to read [How to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve the possibilities to help the user who ask. You should explain your approach.

Comment: I just tried this and it gives me exactly what I want. Thank you so much. Now I need some time to understand every line :)

Comment: To get all the digit of the given number there is no need to use the math module and log for that matter, I know you use the log10 to get the length of the number, but you don't need to, because your number will get smaller in each iteration use that as your control in a while loop, for example `while n>0: n,digit = n//10, n%10` here when n is just one digit diving it by 10 will give you 0 and thus ending the loop ( `//` is the integer division, `a//b` is like `int(a/b)` but is better )